# How to effectively monitor PostgreSQL 9.5 Replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.5

**Background**: I've got quite some experience running and automating MySQL Clusters with several independent replication streams. However I rarely had to run an PostgreSQL replication myself. They were either managed by some other team or fully managed Amazon RDS. Now I need care for a replicated PostgreSQL setup myself and need some help.

We've got an PostgreSQL 9.5 setup with (at least) one slave replicating from a master. Mostly for failover purposes. We are **not** running a real HA setup (yet).

For Monitoring we use Prometheus and an PostgreSQL *Exporter* for Prometheus. This service executes queries and provides the results to the monitoring system.

With MySQL monitoring the replication process was easy. You had to make sure that the slaves were streaming binlogs from the server and applying those locally. Usually it was OK to just check for the **Seconds_Behind_Master**. With PostgreSQL it seems to be a [little harder](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADKbJJWz9M0swPT3oqe8f9+tfD4-F54uE6Xtkh4nERpVsQnjnw@mail.gmail.com).

**Question**: **What are the most important metrics**/properties **to make sure my replication is running properly** and that we can promote the slave to a master any time?

Comment: It is hard to answer your question because there are some metrics/properties such as Network (check alive), WAL latency (size, time) (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/monitoring-stats.html), WAL keep segment, archive log, FSM and VSM problems (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Free_Space_Map_Problems) and so on.  However, about replication, I think you can monitor Network & WAL latency. In terms of switch slave to new master, It depends on your configurations, you can compare WAL latency between old-new master (if any) before switching.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. With MySQL it wasn't as easy a watching the Seconds_Behind_Master, but this was the single most important metrics wrt. Replication, given you got the basics covered. I intentionally asked for the most important metric(s) to watch out for. I fully understand that this won't cover all failure scenarios.